# Proxy Error with redis on openshift

Tags: python, redis, openshift

I'm running a python app on openshift with redis as the data store.

Over the past couple of days the app has stopped working

When I send a request via postman to my app I see:

```
Proxy Error

The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /index.

Reason: Error reading from remote server
```

when I log in to my app:

```
$ rhc tail myapp
```

I see:

```
==> app-root/logs/python.log <==
[Sat Aug 22 18:19:29 2015] [error] \t\t\t\tvalid = true;\r
[Sat Aug 22 18:19:29 2015] [error] \t\t\t}\r
[Sat Aug 22 18:19:29 2015] [error] \t\t}\r
[Sat Aug 22 18:19:29 2015] [error] \t}\r
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.2.78.1:8080
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs
(98)Address already in use: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.2.78.1:8080
no listening sockets available, shutting down
Unable to open logs

==> redis/logs/redis.log <==
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'
          `-._        _.-'
              `-.__.-'

[133622] 25 Aug 12:04:29.516 # Server started, Redis version 2.6.13
[133622] 25 Aug 12:04:29.516 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory =
 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
[133622] 25 Aug 12:04:29.516 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
[133622] 25 Aug 12:04:29.516 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
```

Again, this app has been working fine with no errors for weeks. Thinking that  my "hobby" redis db was full, I tried flushall, but the problem persists.

How can I fix this?

edit:

````
[133622] 25 Aug 13:22:52.715 # User requested shutdown...
[133622] 25 Aug 13:22:52.715 * Saving the final RDB snapshot before exiting.
[133622] 25 Aug 13:22:52.735 * DB saved on disk
[133622] 25 Aug 13:22:52.735 * Removing the pid file.
[133622] 25 Aug 13:22:52.735 # Redis is now ready to exit, bye bye...
[394414] 25 Aug 13:22:52.830 * Max number of open files set to 10032
                _._
           _.-``__ ''-._
      _.-``    `.  `_.  ''-._           Redis 2.6.13 (00000000/0) 64 bit
  .-`` .-```.  ```\/    _.,_ ''-._
 (    '      ,       .-`  | `,    )     Running in stand alone mode
 |`-._`-...-` __...-.``-._|'` _.-'|     Port: 6379
 |    `-._   `._    /     _.-'    |     PID: 394414
  `-._    `-._  `-./  _.-'    _.-'
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |           http://redis.io
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
 |`-._`-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'_.-'|
 |    `-._`-._        _.-'_.-'    |
  `-._    `-._`-.__.-'_.-'    _.-'
      `-._    `-.__.-'    _.-'
          `-._        _.-'
              `-.__.-'

[394414] 25 Aug 13:22:52.834 # Server started, Redis version 2.6.13
[394414] 25 Aug 13:22:52.834 # WARNING overcommit_memory is set to 0! Background save may fail under low memory condition. To fix this issue add 'vm.overcommit_memory =
 1' to /etc/sysctl.conf and then reboot or run the command 'sysctl vm.overcommit_memory=1' for this to take effect.
[394414] 25 Aug 13:22:52.834 * DB loaded from disk: 0.000 seconds
[394414] 25 Aug 13:22:52.834 * The server is now ready to accept connections on port 6379
````

Comment: That error looks more like it has to do with an upstream web server proxying your uwsgi app then anything to do with a redis failure.  In other words, it looks like it's a problem with the web server connecting to your app rather than your app connecting to redis.  The redis log looks like it's starting up and running fine.  The already in use error looks like you're trying to restart the app and it can't because it's already running which without any further information would lead me to believe your app is hung.  Can you forcefully kill your app process and then try to restart it?

Comment: I've restarted the app from inside the gui. However I'm still getting the same error. please see the output above.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that redis log.  Your redis server is up and running fine.  The only thing that looks all that out of the ordinary in the logs that you've posted is the address already in use-- which indicates either that you've already got something else running on port 8080 and your app can't start because of that, or that your existing app isn't shutting down properly and is still running.  What level of access do you have to the server?  If you have terminal access, you should be able to figure out what process is binding up port 8080 by running a netstat -anp | grep 8080

Comment: I'm getting :  sudo netstat -anp | grep 8080
bash: /usr/bin/sudo: Permission denied

Comment: @user61629 `netstat --listen -A inet` for listening ports

Comment: It might be tough to get the process id of whatever has the port open without root access.  Assuming whatever it is supports HTTP and it's actually up and responding (and neither of those are really safe assumptions), the following perl command may give you a clue as to what it might be:  perl -MLWP::UserAgent -e 'print LWP::UserAgent->new->get("http://127.2.78.1:8080")->as_string'

Comment: Hi guys, I've been messing around with the filesystem and removed the redis config file which is now not starting. I'm going to ask a follow up question on how to remove a openshift cartridge. On the bright side I've come across https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-common-rhc-commands.html, which lists rhc app-force-stop among other commands which may be useful. I'll need to repair redis first though